# Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: data:image/png;base64, error in google charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, pygooglechart

I want to create google chart into png but it is not working in chrome. Please provide me solution for this. I don't understand what is wrong with this code because this code is working properly in Firefox. Here is my code-

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    arrayData = [
        ["Element", "Percent", { role: "style" } ],
        /*["Gross Margin", 5.94, "#00aeef"],
        ["Operating Margin", 10.49, "#00aeef"],
        ["Net Profit", 19.30, "#00aeef"],
        ["Before Interest and Tax Margin (EBIT)", 21.45, "color: #00aeef"]*/
      ]
    function drawChart() {
    //console.log(arrayData);

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { 
                        calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" 
                       },
                       2]);
      var options = {
        title: "Profitability Indicators(%)",
        width: 555,
        height: 400,
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
        legend: { position: "none" },
         vAxis: {
            baselineColor:'Black',
            textPosition: 'none',
            gridlines: {
                color: 'transparent'
            }
        }
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
      chart.draw(view, options);

      document.getElementById('columnchart_values').outerHTML = '<a href="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">Printable version</a>';
  }
```

Comment: to clarify ... you get the error when you click on the link you've created - `'<a href="' + chart.getImageURI() + '"> ...etc` - otherwise, the code runs fine? If that's the case, that seems to be how chrum works - doesn't let you "navigate" to a data url - probably a *security* thing

Comment: yes, I got the error when I click to the print button, but this is code is perfectly working in firefox.

Comment: that's because firefox is not chrum. Must be a security thing - you'll need to rethink how you do this I think - is the point to download the image? if so, there's a library called `filesaver.js` that works pretty well